# Completeness of subset of metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal C[a,b]$ be the space of continuous function $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ with supremum metric. Let $l,m$ be fixed real numbers. Prove that the subset of $\mathcal C[a,b]$ consisting of all functions $f$ with $l\le f(t)\le m$, for all $t\in[a,b]$ is a complete metric space under induced metric.

What I know that is " A space is complete iff every Cauchy sequence in Space converges in space". Problem is that I'm unable to show this thing. Help me to prove this. Different methods are also invited.

Thank You.

Comment: A subset of a complete metric space is complete under the induced metric if and only if it is closed.

Comment: A more general result is that if $X$ is a set, then the space of bounded real valued functions of domain $X$ with the supremum metric is complete. You can try to prove this one, and then prove that for $X = [a;b]$, $\mathcal{C}[a;b]$ is a closed subset of this space. (it is not more difficult that proving the result directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you have a convergent sequence $f_n$ that satisfies $l \leq f_n \leq m$ for all $n$, then this sequence must have a limit in your original space if you know completemness of the original space. So just prove the limit $f$ also satisfies $l \leq f \leq m$.

Comment: $f_n$ be sequence in subset then it will definitely converge  in $\mathcal C[a,b]$ as it is complete. so proof will be finished if converging function lies in subset, Now how to show this?

Comment: @Chiranjeev Just show that the limit $y$ of a convergent sequence of numbers $y_n$ that satisfy $l \leq y_n \leq m$ must also satisfy $l \leq y \leq m$.

Comment: Thnak you for Helping me

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can use that is $M$ is a complete metric space, then $X \subset M$ is complete if and only if $X$ is closed (can you prove this?). Notice that $({\cal C}[a,b], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete (proof?). And it is easy (?) to see that $$\{  f \in {\cal C}[a,b] \mid l \leq f(t) \leq m,\hspace{2 pt}\forall\,t\in[a,b]\}$$ is closed.

Comment: It is easy to see that it is closed but it is not easy for me to show it contain all of it's limit points, Guide me to show this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do it like this: call that set $A$. Take $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}\subset A$, and suppose that $f_n \stackrel{\|\cdot\|_\infty}{\longrightarrow} f$. Show that $f \in A$.

Comment: Thnak you for Helping me